# Perform multiple bake types automatically

Tags: texture-baking

I'd like to bake some high poly models to low poly to import them into Unity. The problem I have is that I have multiple parts that go on the same texture, and I need color, normals, ambient occlusion, emission textures.

This makes for a highly tedious workflow of changing one setting, bake.
Are there any tools to make baking all maps more efficient?

Comment: https://blendermarket.com/products/baketool

Comment: ^ Note that Baketool is not free.  I recommend Bake Wrangler (free).  It uses nodes which is more flexible.

Comment: ^ Edit: Bake Wrangler is no longer free. I recommend scripting yourself.